# Segmentation Fault with Hash Tables

Tags: c, hash, linked-list

I am trying to create a hash table, an array of linked lists more accurately, I have used the add function for the linked list and works perfectly but when trying this for the hash table it produces a segmentation error.

```
void create_HTable(FILE* book, list* hashTable[1009])
{
  char word[20];
  read(word,book);
  while(strcmp(word,"EOF")!=0)
  {
    int hash_number = hash(word,1009);
    list* node = hashTable[hash_number];
    node = add(node,word);
    read(word, book);
  }
}

list *add(list *old_list, char new_word[20])
{
  //this is a special case when the head of the list is empty
  if(old_list==NULL)
  {
    return insert(new_word,NULL);
  }
  else
  {
    list *new_list = old_list;
    if (doesExist(new_list, new_word, true) == 0)
    {
      while (new_list->next !=NULL)
      {
        new_list = new_list->next;
      }
      new_list->next=insert(new_word,NULL);
    }
    return old_list;
  }
}
```

this works for a normal linked list but when I try to reuse this in my hash table function it crashes.

Comment: Why are you comparing with `"EOF"`? The file does not contain `"EOF"` in any form, it's just an integer that is returned by some functions to indicate that you have gone after the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` function returns the new list head. This:

```
list* node = hashTable[hash_number];
node = add(node,word);
```

will not update the head pointer in the hash table. It will assign the new head to the local variable `node`, which goes out of scope immediately. Use:

```
hashTable[hash_number] = add(hashTable[hash_number], word);
```

The repetition of the head node is not very elegant and it is easy to forget to store the new head pointer. Consider rewriting your `add` function so that the first argument is a pointer to the head pointer, which you can then update.

That error doesn't explain the segmentation fault, however. Have you initalised all 1009 head pointers tom `NULL`? Is your hash function guaranteed to return a number between 0 and 1008? You don't show the hash function, but your hash code is a signed integer. It is very common to make hash codes unsigned, so that arithmetic overflow will never create negative numbers. (Somewhat surprisingly, `(-a) % 1009` is negative in C.)